# Word for dismay about what someone is about to say?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is noun that can be used to express weariness or dismay about what someone is about to say? I looked at a few different sites and no words came up.

Example:

> Howie looks at his brother with _________, but holds his tongue, knowing what his brother is about to say won't be nice, but not wanting to start trouble beforehand.

I originally used the word "consternation," but I don't feel as if that is the right word to describe this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what is coming and can't do a thing to change or stop it, you can say it like this:

"Howie looks at his brother with ***"resignation"***, but holds his tongue, knowing what his brother is about to say won't be nice, but not wanting to start trouble beforehand."

***"Resignation"*** as defined by [MW-O](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resignation) (and other dictionaries - typically the 2nd definition):

> the feeling that something unpleasant is going to happen and cannot be changed

Answer (score 2):

***foreboding***, from [Dictionary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/foreboding)

> If something doesn’t "bode" well, it means that the future doesn't
>   look good. A foreboding is a glimpse or a feeling that bad things are
>   going to happen. It's a premonition, or look into the future. Most
>   times foreboding implies that something evil is coming, but sometimes
>   it's used for anything bad up ahead, as in "**she had a foreboding that
>   the trip would get canceled due to the hurricane**." Even if the future
>   looks bright, a foreboding casts dread over what's ahead.  (emphasis added)

Answer (score 0):

[**Reproach**](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reproach), from ODO

> 1. The expression of disapproval or disappointment:
>
> *"he gave her a look of reproach"*

[**Reproof**](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reproof), from ODO

> An expression of blame or disapproval
>
> *"she welcomed him with a mild reproof for leaving her alone"*

Also kind of related, but not exactly the same meaning,
[**Dissent**](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dissent), from ODO

> The holding or expression of opinions at variance with those commonly or officially held:
>
> *"there was no dissent from this view"*

Or simply, **disapproval**, **disagreement**, **dismay**, etc.